# How to always keep ng-multiselect-dropdown open?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ng-multiselect-dropdown

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown

> I am using this ng multiselect dropdown in angular and I want to keep
> it always open. I tried using defaultOpen option but it goes away
> soon.

HTML CODE:

```
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown
  [placeholder]="'custom placeholder'"
  [settings]="dropdownSettings"
  [data]="dropdownList"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
  (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
  (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

TS CODE:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IDropdownSettings } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dropdownList = [];
  selectedItems = [];
  dropdownSettings = {};
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dropdownList = [
      { item_id: 1, item_text: 'Mumbai' },
      { item_id: 2, item_text: 'Bangaluru' },
      { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
      { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' },
      { item_id: 5, item_text: 'New Delhi' }
    ];
    this.selectedItems = [
      { item_id: 3, item_text: 'Pune' },
      { item_id: 4, item_text: 'Navsari' }
    ];
    this.dropdownSettings:IDropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: 'item_id',
      textField: 'item_text',
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      itemsShowLimit: 3,
      allowSearchFilter: true
    };
  }
  onItemSelect(item: any) {
    console.log(item);
  }
  onSelectAll(items: any) {
    console.log(items);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official [custom theme guide](https://github.com/NileshPatel17/ng-multiselect-dropdown/blob/master/custom-theme.md) so that you get access to the scss of the component. (The link to the scss file in guide is broken, but you can get the scss file from [the official sample code which they provid](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/custom-theme-p1556?))

When you have the scss file added to your solution, open it and add display:block; to the .dropdown-list section. This will force the dropdown to stay open.

```
.dropdown-list {
  display:block; //ADD THIS LINE
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #959595;
  ul {
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  li {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .filter-textbox {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    input {
      border: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 0px 0px 0px 26px;
    }
    input:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
  }
}
```